# Start infinite python script in new thread within Flask

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, process, daemon

I'd like to start my never ending Python script from within Flask request:

```
def start_process():
    exec(open("./process/main.py").read(), globals())
    print("Started")
    return
```

and with the request:

```
@app.route("/start")
   def start():
   from threading import Thread
   thread = Thread(target=start_process, args=())
   thread.setDaemon(True)
   thread.start()
   return redirect(url_for('main'))
```

The `main.py` process is a little test server that waits for some messages, but it simply hangs the entire flask script (in fact, through gunicorn, if I send CTRL-C, I can see the output of the subprocess).

How can I make the `main.py` script start separately?

Answer (score 1):

I've not successfully started long-running threads from within Flask, but have gone the other way: starting Flask in a thread and providing it a way to communicate with other threads.

The trick is to something along the lines of

```
def webserver(coordinator):
    app.config['COORDINATOR'] = coordinator
    app.run(use_reloader=False)
    # use_reloader=False is needed to keep Flask happy in a thread

def main():
    coordinator = Coordinator()
    ui = threading.Thread(target=webserver, args=(coordinator,))
    ui.start()
    # start other threads, passing them coordinator
    # start long-running tasks in main thread, passing it coordinator
```

Where `Coordinator` uses `threading` facilities (e.g., `Lock`, `Queue`) to protect access to shared data or resources. You can fairly easily set up the coordinator to support have worker threads block until signaled (from a handler), then start long-running tasks.

Comment: It does the reverse of what I want to do, but it's always a sort of solution.